# Running C/C++ code with VS code always throw "exited with code=1 in 0.123 seconds"

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VScode to be able to the "Code Runner" package for C and C++ code with the Code Runner package, but it would always error with:

```
[Running] cd "d:\Desktop\Programming\For_fun\tester\" && g++ practice.cpp -o practice && "d:\Desktop\Programming\For_fun\tester\"practice

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.123 seconds
```

I have discovered that compiling and running with wsl and ubuntu would work, but regular command prompt wouldn't. I presume that is a big indicator of what the problem is, but I have no idea how to resolve it or even start googling.

I am on Windows 10

This is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

And these are the results of me trying to confirm whether I have the relevant packages installed:

```
PS D:\Desktop\Programming\For_fun\tester> c++ --version
c++.exe (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

PS D:\Desktop\Programming\For_fun\tester> gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

PS D:\Desktop\Programming\For_fun\tester> g++ --version
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to compile and run completely in the shell (command prompt). The command to compile is clear from your log: `g++ practice.cpp -o practice`. Does it show any error?

Comment: It doesn't work. But I fixed the problem:
Basically, I used the windows finder to find all instances of gcc.exe and deleted the folders within my program files that house them. Then I removed their paths from my environment variables. Finally I did a clean reinstall of gcc-core and gcc-g++ through cygwin and it worked.

Comment: So it was a faulty installation. You might like to delete your question or write an answer yourself, to mark it later. Please don't keep it open.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll copy and paste it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work. But I fixed the problem: Basically, I used the windows finder to find all instances of gcc.exe and deleted the folders within my program files that house them. Then I removed their paths from my environment variables. Finally, I did a clean reinstall of gcc-core and gcc-g++ through cygwin and it worked